# watermarked asp.net form validation using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have an asp.net form with watermarks like this:

```
   <form id="form1" runat="server">

<div class="form-inner">
                            <asp:TextBox ID="firstname" runat="server" value="First Name *" title="First Name *"
                                class="water"></asp:TextBox>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="lastname" runat="server" value="Last Name *" title="Last Name *"
                                class="water"></asp:TextBox>
                            <%--<input name="" value="Address *" title="Address *" type="text" class="water"/>--%>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="Address" runat="server" value="Address *" title="Address *" class="water"></asp:TextBox>
                            <%-- <input name="" value="City *" title="City *" type="text" class="water"/>--%>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="City" runat="server" value="City *" title="City *" class="water"></asp:TextBox>
                            <div>
                                <asp:DropDownList ID="drpStates" runat="server" CssClass="inpt">                                    
                                <asp:ListItem Selected="True">State*</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem>ACT</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem>NSW</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem>NT</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem>SA</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem>VIC</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem>WA</asp:ListItem>
                                </asp:DropDownList>

                                <%--  <input class="inpt" name="postalcode" id="postalcode" value="Postcode *" type="text"/>--%>
                                <asp:TextBox ID="postalcode" runat="server" class="inpt" title="Postcode *" value="Postcode *"></asp:TextBox>
                            </div>
                            <%-- <input name="" value="Phone number *" title="Phone number *" type="text" class="water"/>--%>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtPhoneNumber" runat="server" value="Phone number *" title="Phone number *"
                                class="water"></asp:TextBox>
                            <%-- <input name="" value="Email *" title="Email *" type="text" class="water"/>--%>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtEmail" runat="server" value="Email *" title="Email *" class="water"></asp:TextBox>
                            <div class="form-term">
                                <div class="chk-up">
                                    <%--<input name="" type="checkbox" value="" />--%>
                                    <asp:CheckBox ID="chkInsurance" runat="server" Text="Yes, include my free $ 15,000 Insurance" />
                                </div>
                                <div>
                                    <%--<input name="" type="checkbox" value="" checked="checked" />--%>
                                    <asp:CheckBox ID="chkNews" runat="server" Text="Yes, I would like to receive latest news" />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="send-btn">
                                <%-- <a href="#">SEND ME A SECURE GOLD PACK</a>--%>
                                <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkSendEmail" runat="server" OnClick="lnkSendEmail_Click">SEND ME A SECURE GOLD PACK</asp:LinkButton>
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

and water mark code is like this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {

        $(".water,.inpt").each(function () {
            $tb = $(this);
            if ($tb.val() != this.title) {
                $tb.removeClass("water");
            }
        });

        $(".water,.inpt").focus(function () {
            $tb = $(this);
            if ($tb.val() == this.title) {
                $tb.val("");
                $tb.removeClass("water");
            }
        });

        $(".water,.inpt").blur(function () {
            $tb = $(this);
            if ($.trim($tb.val()) == "") {
                $tb.val(this.title);
                $tb.addClass("water");
            }
        });
});
```

I want to validate this form but due to water marks it is not being validated.

I am using this plugin for validation.

http://jquery.bassistance.de/validate/demo/themerollered.html

Please suggest me solution to it.

Thanks

Comment: Is it possible for you to post a live link to your problem and describe what is not working the way you had hoped?  Or, post a screenshot or something?

Comment: There's no validation code shown?  What doesn't work?  What exception do you get and when, or what do you to expect to happen, when, and what actually happens?

Comment: I guess you could, upon form submission, empty all ".water,.inpt" for which val()==title

Comment: @user1477388: water mark is working but validation is not fired because textboxes are not empty.

Comment: It's hard to understand.  Isn't watermark just a class that you're adding?  So, shouldn't the textboxes still be empty.  Also, validation should fire just when boxes are empty, but when they have the wrong data in them, too.

Comment: @user1477388: yes water mark is a class with some text greyed out in text boxes like 'enter first name', and when validator sees this text, it doesn't fire required field validator..

Answer (score 0):

Making some assumptions about the way you initalize your validator, you may try to replace both the element and form functions of your validator ( http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Validator/element#element and http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Validator/form )

Here is an example with the element function:

```
    $().ready(function() {
        var myValidator = $("form")
                          .validate({...,
                                success: ...,
                                rules:... 
                         });

        // save the 'element' function              
        myValidator.elementSave = myValidator.element;
        // create a new 'element' function that reinit the unchanged watermarked input
        // before performing check with the 'saved' element function
        myValidator.element = function (elem) {
            if (!($(elem).is('.water,.inpt')))
                return myValidator.elementSave(arguments);
            else {
                var save = $(elem).val();
                if (save == elem.title)
                    $(elem).val('');
                var result = myValidator.elementSave(arguments);
                $(elem).val(save);
                return result;
                }
        };
    });
```